# how to choose which one holds?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

let $X$ be any set with the property that for any two metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ on $X$, the identity map

$id:($X$,d_1$)$\to ($X$,d_2)$ is Continuous.

which of the following are true?

1) $X$ must be a singleton.

2) $X$ can be any finite set.

3) $X$ cannot be finite.

4) $X$ may be infinite but not uncountable.

how to solve this? help me

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1) Every metric space is Hausdorff

2)Every finite Hausdorff space has the discrete topology.

Can you choose the right option now? Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Added: To rule out $4$, consider the metric $d_1$ inherited by $\mathbb Z$ by embedding it in $\mathbb R$ by the function $\phi$, where $\phi(n)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n\neq 0$ and $\phi(0)=0$.   Let $d_2$ be the usual metric of $\mathbb Z$.   The singleton $\{0\}$ is an open set in $(\mathbb Z,d_2)$ but it is not open in $(\mathbb Z,d_1)$ because every interval around $0$ contains infinitely many terms of the form $\frac{1}{n}$. So the identity map from $(\mathbb Z,d_1)$ to $(\mathbb Z,d_2)$ is not continuous.

Comment: yes i got answer b. but could it be infinite?

Comment: Try some simple metrics you know on the integers $\mathbb Z$. You should be able to rule it out pretty quickly.

Comment: in my notes d is also true

Comment: see the counter-example I added

Comment: you are right but what question requirement is is there exist any X infinite for which result holds

Comment: even though it holds for not many X but one

Comment: Well, you can embed the integers into any infinite set right? So this counterexample will work for any infinite set.

Comment: means X can never be infinite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36002/discussion-between-jake-and-user290972).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you know that all the norms over $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent. Then you function is continuous if you choose $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d_1$ $d_2$ metrics induced by norms over $\mathbb{R}$. In fact $ \exists c \in \mathbb{R}: d_2(x,y) \le c \ d_1(x,y)$ and if you take a succession $(x_n)$ of real numbers convergent to $x$ for the metric $d_1$ you have 
$$ d_2(id(x_n),id(x))=d_2(x_n,x) \le c \ d_1(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0 $$ then $id$ is continuous. This answers 1,3,4.
For 2: it's true because if a succession $(x_n)$ tends to $x$ in a finite set then it's definitively equal to $x$, meaning that definitively $d_1(x_n,x)=0$. But Then also $d_2(id(x_n),(x))=d_2(x_n,x)=0$ definitively.

Comment: your options are?

Comment: what options about what? do you mean the answers?

Comment: Yes. i mean that

Comment: what about 4th?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable the 4th is false

Comment: It is not true that all metrics over $\mathbb R$ are equivalent. Take a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $[0,1]$ and give $[0,1]$ the usual topology of an interval. Then this is not equivalent to the usual metric on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it using the norms, and now it should work better.